# Aviarc Cannot Create Null Databroker

Tags: aviarc

Just wondering if any one might now how to fix this issue.
Every part of the databroker is created and also all the database connectivity is functional.
But once we try to place them together we come up with a error saying cannot create Null Databroker.

The thing that is really strange is that we have databrokers that are basicly the exact same working.

Can any one shine some light on this issue?

Comment: Did you recompile your application after creating the databroker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We worked on this together today. We did three things to troubleshoot and fix the problem:

1. we changed the calling workflow so that the dataset is refreshed inside the show-screen tags (previously, this was done before the screen was called).
2. we refreshed the dataset (a H2 db) and connected the database (before, it showed as pool not open)
3. we changed the database name to main

It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

"Null databroker" suggests that the broker was not created correctly, although it doesn't look like that was the case since you don't mention having to modify it to get it to work.

In these cases it can be useful to look at the error logs through the admin app to see if there are errors being thrown at some time other than compile time.